# JPanel resizes when parent frame is set to not resizable

Tags: java, swing, jframe

Have built a small test SWING app with three panels.  A main JPanel, that contains two smaller ones.  One on the left (board panel), the other on the right (side panel).  Both inner panels are set to a requested specific size by calling min,preferred, and max size methods.  A button in the right panel sets the parent JFrame to not re-sizable. Everything looks great until the parent frame is set to non-resizable, which causes(?!) a resize of the frame and main panel, which get larger.

Looking for why the resize occurs, and what can be done to keep the main panel and frame sized to enclose just the two inner panels, and no more, once the frame is frozen.

Have highlighted panel borders and added paint event logging to debug sizing issues.

Thanks for the help and insight!

edit:
Appears this issue is in JRE 8. In JRE 9 it goes away, but introduces a scaling problem.  The whole application gets scaled up on my 4k monitor, running Windows 10.

```
package org.fubar;

import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.BoxLayout;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.Window;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

public class PanelTest {

    private static final String appTitle    = "JPanel Test by Fubar.org(c)";

    public static JFrame myFrame                    = null;
    public static JPanel mainPanel                  = null;
    public static JPanel boardPanel                 = null;
    public static JPanel sidePanel                  = null;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                createAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
    }

    private static void createAndShowGUI() {

        System.out.println("Create and show GUI");

        JFrame myFrame = new JFrame(appTitle);
        myFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        mainPanel = new MainPanel();
        myFrame.add(mainPanel);

        myFrame.pack();
        centreWindow(myFrame);
        myFrame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void centreWindow(Window frame) {
        Dimension dimension = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
        int x = (int) ((dimension.getWidth() - frame.getWidth()) / 2);
        int y = (int) ((dimension.getHeight() - frame.getHeight()) / 2);
        frame.setLocation(x, y);
    }

    public static void barfSize(JPanel panel, String panelName) {
        Dimension panelSize = panel.getSize();
        System.out.println(String.format("%s size:(%d,%d);",panelName,panelSize.width,panelSize.height));
    }

}

class MainPanel extends JPanel {

    static final long serialVersionUID = 1;

    public MainPanel() {

        setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.green));

        setLayout(new BoxLayout(this, BoxLayout.X_AXIS));

        PanelTest.boardPanel = new BoardPanel();
        PanelTest.boardPanel.setAlignmentY(TOP_ALIGNMENT);
        add(PanelTest.boardPanel);

        PanelTest.sidePanel = new SidePanel();
        PanelTest.sidePanel.setAlignmentY(TOP_ALIGNMENT);
        add(PanelTest.sidePanel);

    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics gooey) {
        super.paintComponent(gooey);
        PanelTest.barfSize(this, "Main Panel");
    }

}

class BoardPanel extends JPanel {

    static final long serialVersionUID = 1;

    public BoardPanel() {

        setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.red));

        Dimension mySize = new Dimension(400,200);
        setMinimumSize(mySize);
        setPreferredSize(mySize);
        setMaximumSize(mySize);

        JLabel lblText = new JLabel("Board Panel");
        add(lblText);

    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics gooey) {
        super.paintComponent(gooey);
        PanelTest.barfSize(this, "Board Panel");
    }
}

class SidePanel extends JPanel implements ActionListener {

    static final long serialVersionUID = 1;

    public SidePanel() {

        setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.blue));

        Dimension mySize = new Dimension(200,200);
        setMinimumSize(mySize);
        setPreferredSize(mySize);
        setMaximumSize(mySize);

        JLabel lblText = new JLabel("Side Panel");
        add(lblText);

        JButton btnFreeze = new JButton("Freeze");
        btnFreeze.setActionCommand("Freeze");      
        btnFreeze.setToolTipText("Click me to freeze frame");
        btnFreeze.setBorderPainted(true);
        btnFreeze.setEnabled(true);
        btnFreeze.addActionListener(this);
        add(btnFreeze);

    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent action) {
        String command = action.getActionCommand();
        if ( command == "Freeze") {
            freezeFrame();
            System.out.println("Froze frame.");
        }
        Dimension panelSize = getSize();
        System.out.println(String.format("Side Panel size:(%d,%d);",panelSize.width,panelSize.height));
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics gooey) {
        super.paintComponent(gooey);
        PanelTest.barfSize(this, "Side Panel");
    }

    public void freezeFrame() {
        JFrame topFrame = (JFrame) SwingUtilities.getWindowAncestor(this);
        Dimension parentSize = this.getParent().getSize();
        topFrame.setMaximumSize(parentSize);
        topFrame.setResizable(false);
    }

}
```

Screen cap 1:
[App before frame resize disabled](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fO5fC.png)

Screen cap 2:
[App after frame resize disabled](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RQ815.jpg)

Run Log

```
Create and show GUI
Main Panel size:(602,202);
Side Panel size:(200,200);
Board Panel size:(400,200);
Main Panel size:(602,202);
Side Panel size:(200,200);
Board Panel size:(400,200);
Froze frame.
Side Panel size:(200,200);
Main Panel size:(618,218);
Side Panel size:(200,200);
Board Panel size:(400,200);
Main Panel size:(618,218);
Side Panel size:(200,200);
Board Panel size:(400,200);
```

Comment: The window decorations change based on the `resizable` property - this is a known side effect.  You could attempt to re `pack` the window.  Also, you can use `JFrame#setLocationRelativeTo` and pass it `null` and it will centre the window, generally better then using `Toolkit.getScreenSize`

Comment: Wow... a question with a real [mcve].  Congratulations on an excellent first question.

Comment: @MadProgrammer that should be an answer, no?

Comment: repacking does not help. already tried.

Comment: Since I'm on Mac, I didn't get the issue, from experience, call `pack` AFTER calling `setResizable` should re-pack the window around the contents

Comment: yep, that's how I originally had it.... tried pack before and after (as a wtf check), but stripped.  After doesn't make sense, tho. The frame, once set to no-resize, will not change size as the result of a pack, even if inner panels are downsized.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you set your JFrame on setResizable(false) when first creating it, the problem will not occur.

```
    JFrame myFrame = new JFrame(appTitle);
    myFrame.setResizable(false);
```

Answer (score -1):

I think the problem is coming where you are putting the `.pack()`. This command automatically sets all the children components to their preferable sizes. So you can either put the `.setResizable(false)` before the `.pack()` command or remove it. But remember, after removing it you have to manually resize all of the children components using alternatives like `.setBounds` or `.setSize()`